# Moving Files between Servers

Tags: java, file, move

I was able to implement moving files from one directory to other in the same system using JAVA URL Connection.But I have to move files from a directory of one server to another(linux or windows) , and I should not use the third party Java APIs. Is there a way how to implement this? If yes , what configuration  details are required in the program.please let me know how to implement it.

Comment: Why do you need to move the files from one server to another?

Comment: There are a lot of servers interconnected , now i want only few particular file types to be moved to specified servers. so there is a need.!

Comment: You will need a server running to handle client requests.  This can be Windows shares, or ftp-servers or something third.  What to use, strongly depends on what tools are available to you.

Comment: the main server gets some  particular files from somewhere else. now these files are filtered based on file extensions,like .mp4 files to be sent some particular Server. So there will not be any client requests.its the main server which is configured to move , when ever a particular file comes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about writing a very small script like below..

```
SOURCEDIR=/home/subodhr/e_books/
DESTDIR=user@server:home/subodhr/Destination/    
rsync -avh --exclude="*.bak" $SOURCEDIR $DESTDIR
```

save this file using `.sh` extension
like **moveFile.sh**
then execute the script as `./moveFile.sh`

Comment: The one you proposed is for inside the same system, what about if i want to move files between two servers.

Comment: put the url of different server like  `DESTDIR=Ÿourserver address`

Comment: but i couldn't use any third party software to implement this ! Is there any way it can be implemented using JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents into serializable objects and pass them across different machines. Once received, just write them to the disk. You should be able to do this using core Java API.

Comment: I got the concept of Serializing but how to pass them across different machines? I cannot use FTP or any other third party APIs !!

Comment: No code should be at only one end,at the main server,and there will be a configuration file which decides to which server the files are to be moved.but at first i want to put all config details in java program, later i will start building the config file.

Comment: Then you cannot do that.  You need functionality on both machines.